# Channel Entries w/ Month, Day, Year Having Issue w/ Localization

Tags: channel-entries, entry-date

Having issues with the following code, if entries are todays date, but past 07:00 PM they do not display. Even with ***show_future_entries="yes"*** unless the entries are dated 06:59 PM or earlier.

`{exp:channel:entries channel="lunch_order" status="open" day="{current_time format='%d'}" month="{current_time format='%m'}" year="{current_time format='%Y'}" show_future_entries="yes"}{lunch_order_account_number} {lunch_order_share_id}   {lunch_formatted_order_total}

{/exp:channel:entries}`

I should also add the Localization is set to UTC-6 CST, and Allow members to set their own localization preferences is set to "No".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Which version of EE?

Comment: ExpressionEngine 2.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching parameters to start_on, stop_before which took care of my issue, not sure why it wouldn't work the other way though.